# Error in using LevelDB in Azure node.js App service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, leveldb

I'm trying to create a Node.js app with LevelDB [module](https://github.com/level/levelup) in Microsoft Azure app service. I followed the steps given in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/) to create an app. I ran that locally (Windows10 64bit) and pushed it to the Azure.  When I open the site in browser, it returns HTTP 500 error.

When I run `npm start` in the terminal on `https://{app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` , it returns the error at.

```
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\levelup\lib\levelup.js:119:34
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\abstract-leveldown\abstract-leveldown.js:39:16
Express server listening on port 3000    

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.4.7\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.15.8\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! appName@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appName@0.0.1 start script 'node app.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the appName package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs appName
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls appName
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
```

I checked the code in `levelup.js:119:34` and added the log for that error. That log returns `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I'm using LevelDB for storing the data. I initialised the db by `var db = levelup('./mydb', { valueEncoding: 'json'});`

What should I do to use the levelDB in Microsoft Azure? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share some code.

Answer (score 0):

According the requirement description at https://github.com/level/levelup#tested--supported-platforms, the module requires `node-gyp` via installation. And Azure App Service does not support all native modules and might fail at compiling those with very specific prerequisites.

Please double check whether modules have been install successfully on Azure Web Apps via Kudu console site, and you can install these modules on your local Windows machine in 32 bit, and deploy the entire application including `node_modules` folder to Azure Web Apps.

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/ for details.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.